# Весь сайт без перезагрузки на jquery

Tags: php, jquery, spa

Какие могут быть подводные камни при создании сайта на jquery без перезагрузки страницы. Менять url через js и контент через json на php. Заинтересовала данная тема скоростью отзывчивости. Стоит ли заморачиваться? Был ли у кого-нибудь опыт разработки подобных проектов?

Comment: Мета для вопросов о ruSO, а вопорсы о программировании надо задавать на SO.

Comment: Для jQuery есть PJAX

Answer (score 2):

По идее, сделать можно всё.

Но стоит отметить, что jQuery - это всего лишь весьма удобная библиотека для взаимодействия с DOM. Она вообще никак не помогает в реализации SPA. Ну ладно, есть метод load, но он всего лишь подменяет содержимое элемента на то, что пришло в ответе на ajax-запрос. Если же передаются данные, а не html-разметка, то всё построентие страницы должно быть на клиенте и jQuery для этого бесполезна (хотя можно подключить какой-нибудь шаблонизатор).

Написать полностью SPA без специализированных фреймвёрков или библиотек, пожалуй, круто и полезно для развития как веб-разработчика. Какого-либо другого практического смысла от этого я не вижу.

Ещё один вариант - оставить всю логику на сервере и просто подменять разметку куска страницы. Это проще и это легко реализуемо на jQuery. Из плюсов - немного другое восприятие пользователем, можно сделать какую-то анимацию перехода. Из минусов - объём передаваемых данных практически не меняется. Потенциальные грабли - если необходимо динамическое подключение разных скриптов на разных страницах, то могут получиться конфликты между различными скриптами, которые вообще не должны были подключаться одновременно, либо начали выполняться в неправильном порядке. К тому же событие ready уже произошло, и его обработчики будут вызываться немедленно.

Если нужно именно нормальное SPA в production-целях, рекомендую взять что-нибудь непосредственно предназначенное для разработки SPA, а не jQuery. С современными фреймвёрками jQuery используется крайне редко, поскольку они сами покрывают основное её использование, а в неосновном и сама jQuery обычно не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

У меня были проблеми с:

1. типами данных.
2. видимостью переменных
3. разной скоростью вызова функций

Заморачиваться стоит, но также стоит помнить, что для таких дел нужен хороший сервер.

Answer (score 0):

Определенно стоит сделать, если позволяет время.

**JQuery**

Что касается самой JQuery - как было отмечено выше это фреймворк, с помощью которого можно быстро написать код на клиенте. В плане производительности и скорости это не лучшее решение, здесь в идеале желательно использовать собственную библиотеку, специально заточенную под требования проекта.

**Более высокие требования к качеству кода**

Если переводите проект на AJAX-загрузку, то имейте ввиду, что потребуется более тщательно проводить разработку и тестирование. Особенно что касается динамически подключаемых файлов с js-скриптами, глобальными переменными, потребуются собственные обработчики событий (например, вместо DOMContentLoaded в аналогичном случае нужно будет вызывать собственный код после получения ajax-данных).

**Производительность и нагрузка**

Если нормально напишите код, то в плане нагрузки на сервер не сильно все поменяется. Просто те запросы, которые шли синхронно будут идти в асинхронном режиме. Плюс немного уменьшится объем передаваемых данных (серверу уже будет не нужно каждый раз отправлять всю страницу целиком).

**Быстрая стартовая загрузка страницы**

Также имейте ввиду, если хотите сделать быструю первоначальную загрузку страницы (например, как в vk, где все работает без загрузки пустого фрейма и последующего ajax-запроса/вставки данных, а сразу все выводится с одного запроса к серверу), то придется по сути делать 2 версии страницы - одну, которая сразу выдается в ответе сервера, а вторая через ajax-загрузку данных.

Особенно этот момент важен для SEO. Поисковые системы могу некорректно проиндексировать страницу, подгружающуюся через пустой фрейм.

Answer (score 0):

Сделать конечно можно любым способом, но стоит подумать о целесообразности. Задача стандартная и правильным решением  будет разделение приложения на фронтенд и бэкенд. Т.е для бэкенда пишем REST приложение на серверном языке, а для фронта используйте JS фреймворк: React, Angular и т.д.

Конечно можно городить свой велосипед:

1. Разрабатывать схему запросов ajax с помощью jquery - и если все получится, то у Вас выйдет свой костыльный js-фреймворк.
2. В бэкенд врейворках есть инструменты для реализации обмена данными ajax с использованием pushHistory. Это тоже не самый лучший вариант,  возможности этих инструментов ограничены, их стоит использовать для локальных задач.